# need help creating a function to delete one wave of data if it's a duplicate of the previous wave for a retrospective measure

Tags: r, function, dataframe, duplicates, data.table

I'm working with a longitudinal dataset that has a retrospective measure of trauma that provides a yes/no endorsement of a question and the age of onset if the answer was "yes". If a question was endorsed at the first wave of data and then again at the second wave with the same age it needs to be converted to a "no" and a the age to NA. My data looks like this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Aw1 = c(0,0,1,0,0),
                          Aagew1 = c(NA,NA,23,NA,NA),
                          Aw2 = c(1,0,1,0,0),
                          Aagew2 = c(29,NA,23,NA,NA),
                          Bw1 = c(1,0,0,0,1),
                          Bagew1 = c(20,NA,NA,NA,23),
                          Bw2 = c(1,0,1,0,1),
                          Bagew2 = c(20,NA,28,NA,23)))
print(df)
  Aw1 Aagew1 Aw2 Aagew2 Bw1 Bagew1 Bw2 Bagew2
1   0     NA   1     29   1     20   1     20
2   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
3   1     23   1     23   0     NA   1     28
4   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
5   0     NA   0     NA   1     23   1     23
```

Using the following data.table syntax I'm able to recode what I want conditionally so that the "A" question at wave two, that is the same incident recorded at wave 1, is no longer present

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[Aagew1 == Aagew2, ':=' (Aw2 = 0, Aagew2 = NA)]
print(dt)
   Aw1 Aagew1 Aw2 Aagew2 Bw1 Bagew1 Bw2 Bagew2
1:   0     NA   1     29   1     20   1     20
2:   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
3:   1     23   0     NA   0     NA   1     28
4:   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
5:   0     NA   0     NA   1     23   1     23
```

I'd like to automate this syntax and put it into a function so that for every question that repeats itself at wave 2 is deleted. Here's a function I made that doesn't work:

```
rm.duplicate <- function(x){
  y <- as.data.table(x)
  for(i in LETTERS[1:2]){
    y[paste0(i,"age","w1") == paste0(i,"age","w2"), ':=' (paste0(i,"w2") = 0, paste0(i,"age","w2") = NA)]
  }
  return(as.data.frame(y))
}
```

The desired outcome is (so that the duplicates at wave 2 are deleted for all the unique questions):

```
Aw1 Aagew1 Aw2 Aagew2 Bw1 Bagew1 Bw2 Bagew2
1:   0     NA   1     29   1     20   0     NA
2:   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
3:   1     23   0     NA   0     NA   1     28
4:   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
5:   0     NA   0     NA   1     23   0     NA
```

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's function can be modified slightly to add `get` to return the value

```
rm.duplicate <- function(x){
  y <- as.data.table(x)
  for(i in LETTERS[1:2]){
      y[get(paste0(i,"age","w1")) == get(paste0(i,"age","w2")), 
           paste0(i,c("", "age"), "w2")  := .(0,  NA)]
    }
   return(as.data.frame(y))
 }

rm.duplicate(df)
#  Aw1 Aagew1 Aw2 Aagew2 Bw1 Bagew1 Bw2 Bagew2
#1   0     NA   1     29   1     20   0     NA
#2   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
#3   1     23   0     NA   0     NA   1     28
#4   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA   0     NA
#5   0     NA   0     NA   1     23   0     NA
```

---

Or another option is `set`

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
 for(i in LETTERS[1:2]){
   w1 <- paste0(i,"age","w1")
   w2 <- paste0(i,"age","w2")
   i1 <- which(dt[[w1]] == dt[[w2]])
   nm1 <- paste0(i,c("", "age"), "w2")
   set(dt, i = i1, j = nm1[1], value = 0)
   set(dt, i = i1, j = nm1[2], value = NA)

 }

dt
```